# Jasmine test with observable and array

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I have an angular application and I am busy with testing with Jasmine.

I have this method:

```
/** Gets the case type info configuration that is used on various views */
    getCaseTypeInfo(spinnerMessage: string): Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]> {
        let result: Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>;
        Iif (this.caseTypeInfoSnapshot) {
            result = of(this.caseTypeInfoSnapshot);
        } else {
            result = this.http.get<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>(`${this.api}/types`, spinnerMessage).pipe(map(i => {
                this.caseTypeInfoStoreService.addCaseTypeInfoToStore(i);
                return i;
            }));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and the unit test for it so far:

```
 // tslint:disable-next-line:no-commented-code
    it('shoud get case type info configuration that is used on various views', () => {
        let result99: Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>;
        result99 =  service.getCaseTypeInfo('spinner') as Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>;
        const castTypeinfoModelTest = new Array<CaseTypeInfoModel>();

        service.getCaseTypeInfo('spinner');
        caseTypeInfoStoreService.addCaseTypeInfoToStore();
        afwHttpMock.setupOnlyResponse(result99, 200);
        expect(castTypeinfoModelTest).toBe(true);

    });
```

but it doesn' twork.

And I get an error on this line:

```
 expect(castTypeinfoModelTest).toBe(true);
```

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
 it('shoud get case type info configuration that is used on various views when snapshot doesnt exists', () => {
        let result99: Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>;
         const spy = spyOn(caseTypeInfoStoreService, 'addCaseTypeInfoToStore');
        result99 = service.getCaseTypeInfo('spinner') as Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>;
        const response = [{ mock: 'mock' } as any];
        service['caseTypeInfoSnapshot'] = response;
        caseTypeInfoStoreService.addCaseTypeInfoToStore();

         afwHttpMock.setupOnlyResponse(result99, 200);
         expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('spinner');
          afwHttpMock.returnSuccessResponse();
    });
```

But this part is still red:

```
i => {
                this.caseTypeInfoStoreService.addCaseTypeInfoToStore(i);
                return i;
```

of this method:

```
 /** Gets the case type info configuration that is used on various views */
    getCaseTypeInfo(spinnerMessage: string): Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]> {
        let result: Observable<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>;
        if (this.caseTypeInfoSnapshot) {
            result = of(this.caseTypeInfoSnapshot);
        } else {
            result = this.http.get<CaseTypeInfoModel[]>(`${this.api}/types`, spinnerMessage).pipe(map(i => {
                this.caseTypeInfoStoreService.addCaseTypeInfoToStore(i);
                return i;
            }));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Would you consider posting the exact error you get? I'm by no means good at javascript, but this will surely help others.

Comment: I have edit the post

Comment: There are a number of things that make your question confusing. Is the error in the test or in the component. You state something is 'red' in the component, but don't include the actual error message. You also state you get an error in your test, but don't include that message either. Which error are you trying to fix and what is the actual error message given?